# When the convex hull of a closed convex cone and a ray is closed?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

Let $C$ be a closed convex cone in a Hausdorff locally convex topological vector space $E$ and let $y \in E$. I wonder a condition under which the conical hull of $C \cup \left\{ y \right\}$, i.e., the set $\left\{ x+\lambda y: x \in C, \lambda \geq 0 \right\}$, is closed.

Any suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C^\ominus = \{ u\in E^* \,|\, \langle u,C\rangle \leq 0\}$ and let $H = \{u\in E^* \,|\, \langle u,-y\rangle \leq 0\}$.

If the interior of $C^\ominus$ meets $H$, or if
$C^\ominus$ meets the interior of $H$, then we have the sum rule
$\partial (\iota_{C^\ominus}+\iota_{H})= \partial \iota_{C^\ominus} + \partial \iota_{H}$. In that case, evaluating at $0$, gives

$$ (C^\ominus\cap H)^\ominus = C+H^\ominus = C+\mathbb{R}_+y\;\;\text{is closed.}$$

Another case arises when $C$ is a polyhedral cone. All the above is true in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and in Hilbert space, and likely in Banach space. I don't know about your very general setting.

Comment: Thank you very much! The condition seems to be valid in a Hausdorff l.c.s.